# Heroku R10 Error while running Spring Boot App

Tags: spring, heroku, boot

I got R10 Error when running Spring boot application in heroku.
I tried most of the proposals in Stack Overflow, but they didn't work for me.

Please help me..

My Procfile

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar -Dserver.port=$PORT -Dspring.profiles.active=prod ./build/libs/SSN-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=$PORT
```

My application.properties

```
server.address=localhost
server.port=${PORT:8080}
```

Logs..

```
2022-11-19T23:12:04.731627+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar -Dserver.port=31021 -Dspring.profiles.active=prod ./build/libs/SSN-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=31021`
2022-11-19T23:12:05.568080+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2022-11-19T23:12:05.572420+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2022-11-19T23:12:07.554745+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-11-19T23:12:07.554775+00:00 app[web.1]:   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2022-11-19T23:12:07.554793+00:00 app[web.1]:  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2022-11-19T23:12:07.554818+00:00 app[web.1]: ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2022-11-19T23:12:07.554843+00:00 app[web.1]:  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2022-11-19T23:12:07.554869+00:00 app[web.1]:   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2022-11-19T23:12:07.554893+00:00 app[web.1]:  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2022-11-19T23:12:07.555829+00:00 app[web.1]:  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.1)
2022-11-19T23:12:07.555859+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-11-19T23:12:08.361956+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:08.357  INFO 4 --- [           main] io.twotle.ssn.SsnApplication             : Starting SsnApplication using Java 17.0.5 on 508919e7-0325-4bb9-8e53-748955d64441 with PID 4 (/app/build/libs/SSN-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by u53593 in /app)
2022-11-19T23:12:08.362497+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:08.362  INFO 4 --- [           main] io.twotle.ssn.SsnApplication             : The following profiles are active: prod
2022-11-19T23:12:11.674272+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:11.674  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2022-11-19T23:12:11.674795+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:11.674  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-11-19T23:12:11.697612+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:11.697  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 5 ms. Found 0 Redis repository interfaces.
2022-11-19T23:12:12.498128+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:12.497  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2022-11-19T23:12:12.499210+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:12.499  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-11-19T23:12:12.671312+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:12.671  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 168 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-11-19T23:12:12.678732+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:12.678  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2022-11-19T23:12:12.678800+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:12.678  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-11-19T23:12:12.683749+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:12.683  INFO 4 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data Redis - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface io.twotle.ssn.repository.UserRepository. If you want this repository to be a Redis repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.KeyValueRepository.
2022-11-19T23:12:12.683829+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:12.683  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 Redis repository interfaces.
2022-11-19T23:12:14.770009+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:14.769  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 31021 (http)
2022-11-19T23:12:15.330804+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:15.330  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-11-19T23:12:15.331066+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:15.330  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
2022-11-19T23:12:15.428399+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:15.427  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-11-19T23:12:15.428403+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:15.427  INFO 4 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6945 ms
2022-11-19T23:12:15.633216+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:15.631  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-11-19T23:12:17.972054+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:17.971  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-11-19T23:12:18.044014+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:18.043  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-11-19T23:12:18.128438+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:18.128  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.1.Final
2022-11-19T23:12:18.343273+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:18.343  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-11-19T23:12:18.479720+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:18.478  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2022-11-19T23:12:20.066360+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:20.066  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-11-19T23:12:20.074778+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:20.074  INFO 4 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-11-19T23:12:22.381991+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:22.381  WARN 4 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-11-19T23:12:22.678994+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:22.678  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@32b0876c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@201c3cda, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@58d6b7b9, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@76332405, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@79c5460e, io.twotle.ssn.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter@2aaf152b, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5d97caa4, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6732726, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@39bbd9e0, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7d0d91a1, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@54402c04, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1df1ced0]
2022-11-19T23:12:23.622667+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:23.622  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 31021 (http) with context path ''
2022-11-19T23:12:24.534472+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-11-19 23:12:24.534  INFO 4 --- [           main] io.twotle.ssn.SsnApplication             : Started SsnApplication in 18.025 seconds (JVM running for 18.961)
2022-11-19T23:12:39.488676+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/swagger-ui/" host=backend-ssn.herokuapp.com request_id=308bce22-08dd-4233-baed-5acfcd6698bc fwd="MYIP" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2022-11-19T23:13:02.551849+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/swagger-ui/" host=backend-ssn.herokuapp.com request_id=99673378-2414-451d-a355-02cb0b28e02f fwd="MYIP" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2022-11-19T23:13:35.061864+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2022-11-19T23:13:35.101053+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-11-19T23:13:35.347922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-11-19T23:13:35.410928+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I can't understand why I get R10 Error.

In local, my code is perfect to run server. (work well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your port appears to be correct. I'm not an expert in Spring, but I *think* you just need to set it once, either in `application.properties` or in your `Procfile` as `-Dserver.port=$PORT`. You've done both of those things. I don't think the `--server.port=$PORT` does anything.

However, you have also set `server.address=localhost` in `application.properties`. Assuming that specifies the interface the server should listen on, that's not correct. `localhost` probably can't receive traffic from outside of the dyno itself.

Try changing it to `server.address=0.0.0.0`, then commit and redeploy. This should instruct Tomcat to listen on all available IP addresses.